# Full state feedback with integral action - Matlab script

Tags: control-theory, systems-engineering, systems-design

I made this Matlab script to implement a dynamical system with full state feedback and integral action.

Maybe I'm wrong in implementing the integral action because the system diverges.

First I converted the continuous time system into discrete time. Then I extended the state and computed the gain to implement full state feedback and integral action.
Probably there is an error in how the integral action is implemented in `for` loop.

Shouldn't "integral in discrete time" simply be the previous sample?

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

A = [ -0.313   56.7  0
     -0.0139 -0.426  0
        0      56.7  0];


B = [0.232
     0.0203
     0];

C = [0 0 1];

%conversion to descrete time 

T = .1;

sys = ss(A, B, C, 0);

sysd = c2d(sys, T);

Ad = sysd.A;

Bd = sysd.B;

Cd = sysd.C;

%extension

A_ext = [ Ad [0 0 0]'
         -Cd    1   ];

B_ext = [Bd
         0];


%desidered poles
p_des = [0.5 0.501 0.502 0.503];

K = -place(A_ext, B_ext, p_des);


Kr = K(1:3);
Ki = K(4);

N = 100;

%desidered output
yd = 0.05;

x(:, 1) = [0 0 0]';

u(:, 1) = yd * Ki + Kr * x(:, 1); %(yd - 0) * Ki + Kr * x(:, 1)
x(:, 2) = Ad * x(:, 1) + Bd * u(:, 1);
y(:, 1) = Cd * x(:, 1);

for i=2:N

      u(:, i) = (yd - y(:, i - 1)) * Ki + Kr * x(:, i);

      if (i < N)
        x(:, i + 1) = Ad * x(:,i) + Bd * u(:, i);
      end
      y(:, i) = Cd * x(:, i);

      
end

k = 1:N;
plot(k, x');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "*Shouldn't "integral in discrete time" simply be the previous sample?*". **No**. The last row of `A_ext` clearly shows that the integral is the *sum* of the previous integrator state and current integrator input (`y_d-y`). I think, that the **accumulation** equation corresponding to the last row of the `A_ext` matrix is not implemented in the for loop.

Comment: And how could it be implemented in the `for` loop? In simulink I simply used the discrete integrator block but how could it be done in command line?

Comment: First and foremost,  **do not "clear"  "clear all"** every time you start work.  That's pointless and potentially desctructive.    Next, learn the difference between a macro and a function.  It's important.   And, don't waste time and memory space renaming field elements ( `Ad = sysd.A`) It does nothing useful.

Comment: You made a common but horrible design error:  inside a `for` loop, that "if" statement is inappropriate and time-wasting.  Shift the index down and remove teh "if"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last row of the extended `A` matrix corresponds to the equation

$$
x_{\mathrm{integrator}}(i+1) = -C_d x_{\mathrm{rest}}(i) + x_{\mathrm{integrator}}(i) = -y(i) + x_{\mathrm{integrator}}(i)
$$

You can use the extended state and matrices inside the `for` loop as such. Alternatively, if you decide to use the original state matrices inside the `for` loop as you have done in the sample code, you need to implement the above equation also in the `for` loop. It will look something like.

```
x_int_cur = 0

for i = ...
   ...

   % equation corresponding to last row of the
   % extended matrix implemented separately
   x_int_cur = (yd - Cd * x(:, i)) + x_int_cur

   u(:, i) = Kr * x(:, i) + x_int_cur * Ki;

   % optional if you want to plot
   % the state of the integrator with respect to time later on.
   x_int_total_history(:, i) = x_int_cur;

   ...
end
```

Note that, in your sample code, you have used the *previous output* `y(i-1)` to feed the integrator. This effectively creates additional states in the system and *doesn't* match the extended state matrix which uses the *current output* to feed its integrator.

Also, note that I have not fully checked the modified code above to see if it is exactly matching the extended state matrices. Use it only as a starting point. The main idea is that you have to implement the same extended system equations which you used to `place` the poles in the `for` loop also.

Comment: Thank you! It works